# react loop through array of strings with delay and set the text value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a loader which shows loading message when passed a string, but when passed an array I want to show multiple messages one after another looping through messages array.

```
const messages = ['fetching from sources...', 'loading account...'];

<Loader message={messages}/>

const Loader = (Props) => {
    const { message } = props;


    const renderMessages = (msgs) => {

        console.log(msgs);
        return msgs.forEach((msg, i) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                return <Message>{msg}</Message>;
            }, 500);
        });
    };

    return (
        <LoaderContainer>
            <LoaderSvg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 100 100" />
            {(Array.isArray(message)) ? renderMessages(message) : <Message>{message}</Message>}

        </LoaderContainer>
    );
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried/investigated?

Comment: @JeroenHeier Well the code clearly shows what OP tried, doesn't it?

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of what could work for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/loop-through-array-with-react-d5tlc (I would suggest reviewing it for edge cases but the core functionality should be close to what you're looking for).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const messages = ["fetching from sources...", "loading account..."];

const Loader = props => {
  const { messages } = props;
  // Default to the first message passed
  const [messageIndex, setMessageIndex] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Move on to the next message every `n` milliseconds
    let timeout;
    if (messageIndex < messages.length - 1) {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => setMessageIndex(messageIndex + 1), 1000);
    }

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, [messages, messageIndex]);

  return <div>{messages[messageIndex]}</div>;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Loader messages={messages} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Nice, that's how I would do it. I don't think `setMessageIndex` needs to be in the useEffect dep array

Comment: @WillJenkins ah yea, you're right. I thought it was hitting the exhaustive dep check linting warning but I was wrong. I update the example to remove `setMessageIndex` from the dep array.

Answer (score 0):

A functional component has to return the jsx to render. What you are trying to do does not work. In case of an array of messages you are returning `msgs.forEach(...)` but [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
 does not return an array but `undefined`.

You will need to use state to queue up the messages one by one and render the contents of that state instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can append message in a variable and return that variable in renderMessage function

```
const renderMessages = (msgs) => {
    let msgList = ""
    console.log(msgs);
    return msgs.forEach((msg, i) => {
        msgList = msgList + "/n" + msg
        setTimeout(() => {
            return <Message>{msgList}</Message>;
        }, 500);
    });
};
```

/n will show next message in new line

Answer (score -1):

What does you program not do as expected?
Do the messages not show?

If you want to render some element while iterating through an aray, i would advise to use `array.map()` rather than `array.forEach()`.